# how to close login page and redirect to another page using mvvm light and Modern UI and dependency injection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

i try to create login form in wpf using mvvm light, if login success,will redirect to another page and close login page.

i success to login , but when try to redirect, still not work.

this my code

my view

```
 <Button Command="{Binding Authorize}" Width="100" Height="30" Margin="-110,20,0,0" Content="Login" /> /*this to login*/
```

My ViewModel

```
    private void AuthorizeUser()
    {
        User usr = new User();
        usr.LoginName = _userName;
        usr.LoginPassword = _password;
        User user = _accountService.AuthenticationUser(usr, 1);
        if (user != null)
        {
            var app = new MainWindow();
            var context = new MainViewModel();
            app.DataContext = context;
            app.Show();

            var test = new RelayCommand<object>((o) => ((Window)o).Close(), (o) => true);
            test.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }
```

i want to redirect to MainWindow,
can some one help me?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not for debugging your code

Comment: i didn't hope stackoverflow debug my code, i just hope someone tell me where my mistake, sorry for disturb your time. thanks

Comment: It's also not for copy / pasting your code and waiting for people to tell you where your mistake is. Any question that's only helpful to you has nothing to do on this site.

Comment: oke, please tell me how to post right question on this site? i just copy to tell how i bind and what i try. i,m not request you or another to give me the code, just give me explanation how should i do

Comment: You can read the help on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i,m new in wpf, i post question to learn more and more. thanks for your time, you are clever theorizing people. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

use messenger lib at mvvm light to solve this.

1). after successfully login, send message to current view
2). check the message
3). close the view

this the example

```
private void AuthorizeUser()
    {
        User usr = new User();
        usr.LoginName = _userName;
        usr.LoginPassword = _password;
        User user = _accountService.AuthenticationUser(usr, 1);
        if (user != null)
        {
            var app = new MainWindow();
            var context = new MainViewModel();
            app.DataContext = context;
            app.Show();

            Messenger.Default.Send(new NotificationMessage("LoginSuccess"));
        }
    }
```

in view

```
public LoginUser()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage>(this, NotificationMessageReceived);
    }

    private void NotificationMessageReceived(NotificationMessage obj)
    {
        if(obj.Notification == "LoginSuccess")
        {
            var test = Window.GetWindow(this);
            test.Close();
        }
    }
```